# Text overlaps when resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I found this nice header **>** https://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon **<** but when I'm resizing window, the text overlaps. In this demo you must resize the window too much, but the problem is when font- size is bigger or if there is more text in menu then it will be overlapsed faster than in this demo.

---

### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Uno</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">Dos</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a href="#">Tres</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

### CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

---

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what you need by giving the container a width of 100% and each of the elements inside the container an equal width to fill the container as well as applying some padding so things don't run together. Try this out:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox on the unordered list and wrap them in case the screen shrinks. Remove the inline displays on the anchor tag.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li ><a href="#">Uno</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#">Dos</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#">Tres</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
    
  </ul>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set container width to 100%.
2. Also removed ul padding so it takes the whole 100% width.
3. Removed body margin.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.two:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover~hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

ul {
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Uno</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">Dos</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a href="#">Tres</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```